# Not able to close modal pop up window

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

My scenario is  to display  messages  from a list one by one on modal pop up window. List will consist of user defined object which has three fields namely Messages,BgColor and TextColor. Modal pop up will have one "NEXT" button and clicking this will show messages on pop up and message will appear in respective background color and text color.

`Main.xhtml`

```
    <rich:popupPanel id="popupOne" modal="true" rendered="#{demoBean.isTrue}">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="popupTwo" >
      <ui:include id="PackStation_OrderNote_Popup" src="/MyXhtml.xhtml">
       <ui:param id="backcolor" name="backcolor" value="#{demoBean.bgColor}"/>
       <ui:param id="textcolor" name="textcolor" value="#{demoBean.textColor}"/>
      </ui:include>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

`MyXhtml.xhtml`

```
    <a4j:outputPanel id="panelone" >
    <h:outputText id="errorMsg" name="errorMsg"  class="pop_outputText" value="#{demoBean.messages}" />
                    <a4j:commandButton id ="btnOne" 
                                       action="#{demoBean.continueMsgSequenece}" 
                                       value="next" 
                                       reRender="popupOne"  
                                       oncomplete="closePOPUP('#{demoBean.messages}');">    
                    </a4j:commandButton>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

Javascript function

```
    function closePOPUP(msg)
                {
                     if(msg==""){
                      //code to close modal popup
                      UI8Layout.doDialogCloseById('popupOne');
                    }
                }
```

if i put "popupOne" in rendered attribute of a4j:commandButton of myXhtml.xhtml. Background color and text color changes  and messages comes when i click NEXT button as expected in modal pop up but,  on clicking "next button" modal pop up does not close up when messsages end.

And if i put "popupTwo" in rendered attribute of a4j:commandButton of myXhtml.xhtml. Background color and text color does not changes in modal pop up but,  on clicking "next button" modal pop up get  closed  when messsages end.

i need to display messages with background color and text color and modal pop up should closed when messages ends.

Messages are coming in sequence as expected.

is my implementation wrong or there is something which i have to deal with ?

Note:  my Javascript function  does not close modal pop up in first case but it closes modal pop up in second case when message ends.

Comment: i have read some where that a4j:commandButton and oncomplete shows some odd Behaviour while navigation or when a4j:commandButton is placed inside a  Ajax panel.  can  anybody through some light on it ? and how a4j:commandButton works ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct attribute for rerendering in RF 4 is just `render`. And putting ids into the "rendered" attribute will not help anything.

Since you want to rerender the whole panel instead of just the message you can control the visibility of the panel that way:

```
<rich:popupPanel show="#{not empty demoBean.messages}" … >
```

Comment: did you mean a4j:commandbutton's reRender attribute sholud be replaced with render ?    but still it is not woking .

Comment: we are using JSF 2 and Rich Faces 3

Comment: Your code does not suggest so, `rich:popupPanel` is not a component in RichFaces 3.

Comment: actually we are using our custom framework. i cant disclose actual code.